# RegEx for BMHT in a sequence

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regular expression.
Abbreviations are as follows:

```
B - Billion
M - Million
T - Thousand
H - Hundred
```

Now, If I say `3M2T` it means `3 million 2 thousand`
But I cannot say `3T2M` or I cannot say `3M2222T`
BMTH should be in a sequence and should follow standard rule to create a number.
I went till this
`([0-9]+[B]){1}+([0-9]+[M])?+([0-9]+[T])?+([0-9]+[H])?` But here B is compulsary.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:\d+B)?(?:\d{1,3}M)?(?:\d{1,3}T)?(?:\dH)?$
```

You can test it here [regexr.com?2thld](http://regexr.com?2thld)

`(?:)` is non capturing group, otherwise the captured part is stored in to a variable

`\d` is equal to `[0-9]`

`?` after a group or a character makes it optional

`+` means one or more

`{1,3}` says at least once at most three occurrences

`[M]` is not needed when there is only 1 character then only `M` is enough

Comment: Thanks for pretty fast answer. I used it and it worked. I would like to get some guidelines to learn regex in more detail.

Comment: @prasanna A very good source of information is [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). It covers a lot of different regex flavors. I dare to say basic regex is everywhere (nearly) the same, but when you get into details there are really diffs that you have to be aware of. For Perl there is here the [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and the [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html). I am sure there are also good tutorials for your programming language. And there are several online tools to test, like the one in my answer

Answer (score 2):

`([0-9]{1,3}B)?([0-9]{1,3}M)?([0-9]{1,3}T)?([0-9]H)?` Takes up to 3 digits for each B/M/T or 1 for H (in that order), each of the groups being optional. Add constraints suiting your needs…
Take note that `[0-9]` is not necessarily equal to `\d`, it depends on regional settings and stuff.

Comment: This also matches the empty string (which may or may not be desirable).

Comment: If I changes the regional setting to something else how can I test that the following doesn't work?